# Avoiding data race of boolean variables with pthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, pthreads

in my code I have the following structure:

Parent thread

```
somedatatype thread1_continue, thread2_continue; // Does bool guarantee no data race?
```

Thread 1:

```
while (thread1_continue) {
  // Do some work
}
```

Thread 2:

```
while (thread2_continue) {
  // Do some work
}
```

So I wonder which data type should be thread1_continue or thread2_continue to avoid data race. And also if there is any data type or technique in pthread to solve this problem.

Comment: `std::atomic<bool>` with C++11.

Comment: How about `std::atomic<bool>`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in basic ***type*** that guarantees thread safety, no matter how small. Even if you are working with `bool` or `unsigned char`, neither reading nor writing is guaranteed to be atomic. In other words: there is a chance that if more threads are independantly working with the same memory, one thread can overwrite this memory only partially while the other reads the trash value ~ in that case the *behavior is undefined*.

You could use `mutex` to wrap the critical section with `lock` and `unlock` calls to ensure the mutual exclusion - there will be only 1 thread that will be able to execute that code. For more sophisticated synchronization there are *semaphores*, *condition variables* or even patterns / idioms describing how the synchronization can be handled using these (*light switch*, *turniket*, etc.). Just study more about these, some simple examples can be found [here](https://github.com/drahosp/PaPP/blob/master/examples/pthreads/pt_mutex.c) :)

Note that there might be some more complex types / wrappers available that wrap the way the object is being accessed - such as [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) template in C++11, which does nothing but internally handles the synchronization for you so that you don't need to do that explicitly. With `std::atomic` there is a guarantee that: *"if one thread writes to an atomic object while another thread reads from it, the behavior is well-defined"*.

Answer (score 1):

For booleans (and others), be sure to avoid

```
thread 1 loop
{
  do actions1;
  myFlag = true;
  do more1;
}

thread 2 loop
{
  do actions2;
  if (myFlag)
  {
    myFlag = false;
    do flagged actions;
  }
  do more2;
}
```

This nearly always works until myBool is set by thread1 while thread2 is in between checking and resetting myBool.  There are CPU-dependent primitives to handle test-and-set, but the normal solution is lock when accessing shared resources, even booleans.